# How to add specific pages in facetwp drop down

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

How can I show specific pages and sub pages in FacetWP drop down.

I have tried to create custom facetwp without any success.
Please help.

Thanks.

Edit:

I followed this tutorial but I think I am missing something:
https://facetwp.com/how-to-create-custom-facet-types/

Comment: I've never used this, but surely it should be a case of just using a new menu? Also - they have a bunch of FAQ's on their website https://facetwp.com/blog/ - did you look through all of these?

Comment: Yes, but i have a different scenario. I want to show only particular pages in one drop down and then the sub pages of the selected page in another drop down.

Comment: I hope that makes sense.